# anything hinting that EXPTIME $\subseteqq$ PSPACE?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, exp-time-algorithms, pspace

Anything or evidence hinting that $$EXPTIME \subseteqq PSPACE$$？

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35371/why-do-we-believe-that-pspace-%E2%89%A0-exptime

Comment: The [Hopcroft-Paul-Valiant theorem](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/~mmorenom/CS433-CS9624/Resources/p332-hopcroft.pdf) says that time-$T$ Turing machines can be simulated in space $O(T / \log T)$. I suppose that theorem could be interpreted as hinting that $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{EXP} = \mathbf{PSPACE}$. (I think it seems much more likely that these classes are not equal, though.)